# Change distinct objects with same fields to generic array in netwonsoft.json

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have a string of JSON where I have a `weapons-tag`, which within contains all the weapons a player is using in a game. Problem is that the tag itself isn't of an array type, thus making it hard to deserialize the objects inside when you are allowed to have up to six weapons at once.

Basically within the weapon-tag I'm getting weapon_1, weapon_2, etc etc even though they are the same type. Here's how the raw data looks:

```
{
"provider": {
    "name": "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive",
    "appid": 730,
    "version": 13513,
    "steamid": "XXX",
    "timestamp": 1449767607
},
"map": {
    "mode": "casual",
    "name": "de_dust2",
    "phase": "live",
    "round": 0,
    "team_ct": {
        "score": 0
    },
    "team_t": {
        "score": 0
    }
},
"round": {
    "phase": "live"
},
"player": {
    "steamid": "XXX",
    "name": ":-)",
    "team": "CT",
    "activity": "menu",
    "state": {
        "health": 100,
        "armor": 100,
        "helmet": true,
        "flashed": 0,
        "smoked": 0,
        "burning": 0,
        "money": 1000,
        "round_kills": 0,
        "round_killhs": 0
    },
    "weapons": { <---- isn't an array
        "weapon_0": {
            "name": "weapon_knife",
            "paintkit": "default",
            "type": "Knife",
            "state": "holstered"
        },
        "weapon_1": {
            "name": "weapon_usp_silencer",
            "paintkit": "default",
            "type": "Pistol",
            "ammo_clip": 8,
            "ammo_clip_max": 12,
            "ammo_reserve": 24,
            "state": "active"
        }
    },
    "match_stats": {
        "kills": 0,
        "assists": 0,
        "deaths": 0,
        "mvps": 0,
        "score": 0
    }
},
"auth": {
    "token": "CCWJu64ZV3JHDT8hZc"
}
}
```

You might say that they aren't in fact objects with the same attributes, but I want them to get treated as such, and instead of having six classes named weapon_1 to weapon_6 I'd want an array of the *generic* type of weapon.

How would I do such a thing in C# and with Newtonsoft.Json.
I realize there probably is an option with some ugly `string.replace` but there *must* be a cleaner way to do this. Any ideas are welcome, as I cannot think of anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to declare the field to be an `IDictionary<string, Weapon>`, for instance:

```
public SortedDictionary<string, Weapon> weapons { get; set; }
```

Then later you can convert that to an array with

```
var weaponList = player.weapons.Values.ToArray();
```

(I suggest using [`SortedDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) since, as you have only six weapons, their correct order looks to be alphabetical order.  If you had 10 or more you would need a custom [`IComparer<string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  The regular `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class does not preserve order.)

See [Serialize a Dictionary](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm).

If you did have 10 or more weapons, you could do the following to get them in the correct order:

```
public class Player
{
    public Player()
    {
        this.weapons = new SortedDictionary<string, Weapon>(new PrefixedNumericStringComparer("weapon_"));
    }

    public string steamid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string team { get; set; }
    public string activity { get; set; }
    public State state { get; set; }
    public SortedDictionary<string, Weapon> weapons { get; set; }
    public MatchStats match_stats { get; set; }
}
```

Using the following comparer:

```
public class PrefixedNumericStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public string Prefix { get; private set; }

    public PrefixedNumericStringComparer(string prefix)
    {
        if (prefix == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.Prefix = prefix;
    }

    #region IComparer<string> Members

    int? GetNumber(string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        if (value.StartsWith(Prefix))
        {
            var s = value.Substring(Prefix.Length);
            int iValue;
            if (int.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.None, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out iValue))
                return iValue;
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var iX = GetNumber(x);
        var iY = GetNumber(y);
        if (iX == null && iY == null)
            return string.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        else if (iX == null)
            return 1;
        else if (iY == null)
            return -1;
        else return iX.Value.CompareTo(iY.Value);
    }

    #endregion
}
```